# How to disable specific row or cell in ng grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{
             displayName: '', 
             cellTemplate: '<center><input id="Btn" type="checkbox"  ng-click="chkCheckboxes(row.entity)" ng-model="chkCheckbox"   /></center>',
              width: 60 },
        { field: 'ClaimCode', displayName: 'Claim Code', width: 10 },
        { field: 'EmployeeId', displayName: 'Employee Id', width: 10 },
        { field: 'ProjectId', displayName: 'Project Id', width: 18 },
        { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description', width: 10 },
        { field: 'TotalAmount', displayName: 'Total Amount', width: 10 },

        { field: 'ReimbursementAmount', displayName: 'Reimbursement Amount ', width: 15 },
        { field: 'ReimbursedStatus', displayName: ' Reimbursed Status', width: 15 },
        { field: 'ClaimStatus', displayName: 'Claim Status', width: 150 },
        { field: 'CreatedDate', displayName: 'Created Date', width: 15, cellFilter: "moment:'DD/MM/YYYY'" },
        { field: 'CreatedBy', displayName: 'Created By', width: 15 },
        { field: 'ModifiedDate', displayName: 'Modified Date', width: 15, cellFilter: "moment:'DD/MM/YYYY'" },
        { field: 'ModifiedBy', displayName: 'ModifiedBy', width: 15 },
        { displayName: '', cellTemplate: '<center><button id="SubmitBtn" type="button"  ng-click="submit(row.entity)"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Submit" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-submit"></span></button></center>', width: 60 },
        { displayName: '', cellTemplate: '<center><button id="delBtn" type="button"  ng-click="delete(row.entity)"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit"  href="#responsive" data-toggle="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></center>', width: 60 },
        { displayName: '', cellTemplate: '<center><button id="delBtn" type="button"  ng-click="delete(row.entity)"  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip"  href="#responsive" data-toggle="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></center>', width: 60 }
```

Comment: We need more info about what youve tried.

Comment: I wanna disable check box or a row of grid based on database condition.